# getting a total count arrays of a multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am wondering if there is a simple way to get the number of nested arrays inside a single multidimensional array. Here is a simple example.

```
 $a = array (
      'x' => 
      array (
        0 => 'a',
        1 => 'b',
        2 => 'c',
        'text' => 
        array (
          0 => 'foo',
          1 => 'bar',
          2 => 'tar',
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'color' => 
          array (
            0 => 'red',
            1 => 
            array (
              0 => 'blue',
              1 => 
              array (
                'yellow' => 
                array (
                  'name' => 'john',
                  0 => 'doe',
                  1 => 
                  array (
                    0 => 'jane',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

`count()` would only echo `1`. I can do a foreach loop, end up getting the correct value, but I am not sure, if anyone can do better. Namely, using the SPL/Iterators.

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of all values at any level? Because a single foreach won't do that. Also, would you count keys where the value is an array if going several levels deep? I mean you could just use like array_walk_recursive and increment a global counter. Or get the result from print_r and substr_count the number of `=>`.

Comment: Basically, I need to count how many arrays exist in `$a`, which would mean, in that sense `$a` would show `9`

Comment: Just to clarify, `9` right? I know you said that, but generally `count()` doesn't count the top level but counts the number of values under an array.

Comment: Yes `9`, because there are 9 arrays inside $a

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this recursively:

```
Class CountArrays{
    public $count = 0;

    function count(array $array){
        foreach($array as $entry){
            if(is_array($entry){
                $this->count++;
                $this->count($entry);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The question says no foreach loop

Comment: @BiVOC to be fair, the question says `I can do a foreach loop...`. There are several ways that a foreach loop can be used that you might not have thought about.

Comment: If that is the case, then I would have asked for a different forms of implementation, using the foreach loop

Comment: Maybe that is just me but I can really get caught up when figuring a recursive function. Yes you can do double recursive function as well, but you do not get better performance, just more complicated logic, with the same end result. Again, maybe just me, but I think it is cleaner this way, and neither is plain foreach, neither overcomplicated recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just make a recursive function that gets a count. Probably something like:

```
/**
 * $n is an initial value if you wanted to add to the count.
 * Typically it would be zero. It is used in the array_reduce
 * $v is the array to count.
 */
function reduce($n, $v){
    //if the value is an array
    if(is_array($v)){
        //increment our count
        $n++;
        //recurse
        return array_reduce($v, 'reduce', $n);
    }
    //not an array, return our existing count
    return $n;
}

var_dump(reduce(0, $a));
//outputs: int(9)
```

There is one major problem with this (and pretty much any solution) and that is references. It is possible to get caught in a loop that goes infinitely deep by having an array with a value that references itself at a higher depth.

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ie9oyQ

Comment: Let me just see if a better solution is there. Nice work though