# How to print spiral array PHP

Tags: php

I have array and this function

$array = array(array(00,01,02,03), array(10,11,12,13), array(20,21,22,23));

```
function spiral($xSize, $ySize, array $matrix) {
$k = 0;
$l = 0;
$xSize--;
$ySize--;

while ($k <= $xSize && $l <= $ySize) {
    for ($i = $l; $i <= $ySize; ++$i) {
        print($matrix[$k][$i] + " ");
    }
    $k++;

    for ($i = $k; $i <= $xSize; ++$i) {
        print($matrix[$i][$ySize] + " ");
    }
    $ySize--;

    for ($i = $ySize; $i >= $l; --$i) {
        print($matrix[$xSize][$i] + " ");
    }
    $xSize--;

    for ($i = $xSize; $i >= $k; --$i) {
        print($matrix[$i][$l] + " ");
    }
    $l++;
}
}
```

but don't working. Function must return this 
00 01 02 03 13 23 22 21 20 10 11 12

but return this
01 23 13 23 22 21 20 10 11 12 11

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: spiral(4, 5, array), where 4 is rows and 5 is columns and array is up

Comment: `$matrix` is a one dimensional array, but you are accessing multiple dimensions with `$matrix[$k][$i]`.

Comment: true, but now return this 01 23 13 23 22 21 20 10 11 12 11 for $array = array(array(00,01,02,03), array(10,11,12,13), array(20,21,22,23));

Comment: Please update you question with this new code, add the current output and add the 30,31,32,33,34 part to the array again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function:

```
function spiral($xSize, $ySize, array $matrix) {
    $m = 0;
    $n = 0;
    $xSize--;
    $ySize--;

    while ($m <= $xSize && $n <= $ySize) {
        for ($i = $n; $i <= $ySize; ++$i) {
            print($matrix[$m][$i] . " ");
        }
        $m++;
        for ($i=$m; $i <= $xSize ; $i++) { 
            print($matrix[$i][$ySize] . " ");
        }
        $ySize--;
        for ($i=$ySize; $i >= $n ; $i--) { 
            print($matrix[$xSize][$i] . " ");
        }
        $xSize--;
        for ($i=$xSize; $i >= $m ; $i--) { 
            print($matrix[$i][$n] . " ");
        }
        $n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You try: spiral(3,4, $array);

Comment: I output in localhost in (4,4,$array): 00 01 02 03 13 23 33 32 31 30 20 10 11 12 22 21. I think you're printing number instead string

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution.
Here's how to print a spiral array:

```
function printSpiralArray($xSize, $ySize, $matrix){
    $printed = [];
    $numElems = $xSize*$ySize;
    $pos = [0,-1];
    $direction = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$numElems;$i++){
        $checkPos = $pos;
        switch($direction%4){
            case 0:
                $checkPos[1]++;
            break;
            case 1:
                $checkPos[0]++;
            break;
            case 2:
                $checkPos[1]--;
            break;
            case 3:
                $checkPos[0]--;
            break;
        }
        if($checkPos[0]>=$xSize || $checkPos[1]>=$ySize || $checkPos[0]<0 || $checkPos[1]<0 || in_array($checkPos[0].'_'.$checkPos[1],$printed)){
            $direction++;
            $i--;
            continue;
        }
        $pos = $checkPos;
        echo $matrix[$pos[0]][$pos[1]]."\t";
        $printed[] = $pos[0].'_'.$pos[1];
    }
}
```

And here's how to build a spiral array with given size:

```
function getSpiralArray($size){
    $matrix = [];
    $numElems = $size*$size;
    $pos = [0,-1];
    $direction = 0;
    $num = 1;
    for($i=0;$i<$numElems;$i++){
        $checkPos = $pos;
        switch($direction%4){
            case 0:
                $checkPos[1]++;
            break;
            case 1:
                $checkPos[0]++;
            break;
            case 2:
                $checkPos[1]--;
            break;
            case 3:
                $checkPos[0]--;
            break;
        }
        if($checkPos[0]>=$size || $checkPos[1]>=$size || $checkPos[0]<0 || $checkPos[1]<0 || isset($matrix[$checkPos[0]][$checkPos[1]])){
            $direction++;
            $i--;
            continue;
        }
        $pos = $checkPos;
        $matrix[$pos[0]][$pos[1]] = $num;
        $num++;

    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slightly altered version of the codes discussed here:
[getting a total count arrays of a multi-dimentional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173891/getting-a-total-count-arrays-of-a-multi-dimentional-array/24174198#24174198)

My version altered would look like:

```
Class CountArrays{
    public $elements = array();

    function count(array $array){
        foreach($array as $entry){
            if(is_array($entry){
                $this->count++;
                $this->count($entry);
            } else {
                $this->elements[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }

}
```